# Is there a significant increase in crimes against Muslims in the US?

Tags: united-states, crime, racism

My sister has recently been accepted for MS/PhD program in a number of universities in US.

The hate crimes on Indians,  in US, appear to have been on a surge. Hailing from a Muslim family, we are really concerned about the atmosphere in Houston, in specific, and in US, in general. Can I expect a safe environment for her?

She is a really talented individual and her not being able to pursue higher education at her dream institute shall be really painful for me to witness. However, her safety is certainly a humongous concern to us.

Comment: Even with the 'surge' of hate crimes against Indians (I honestly believe its mainly a surge in media coverage more than a surge in actual crime), there is still an exorbitantly low chance of your sister being the victim of a crime. Possible? Yes. You didn't need Trump for that. More likely than rural India? No.

Comment: "have been on a surge" - *\[citation please\]*. And I don't mean mass media which breathlessly reports every single fake/hoax event without fact checking.

Comment: You are in more danger from random street crime and death by car accident in Houston.

Comment: If you're wanting information from a practical perspective, I think the expats Stack Exchange may be more useful than a Stack Exchange, where we talk about it from a theoretical perspective.

Comment: @user4012 The entire point of this question is to find out if it's true or not. If they had a citation, they wouldn't be here asking. Try not to cut out the word "appear" when it completely changes the meaning like this. They're trying to determine if their subjective impressions are backed by data.

Comment: @Chris Hayes, exactly my point. Our perception of no are based on the generics that we hear from media. Judging and making decisions based on just that, is certainly not a good idea. Thus, we wanted to know more on the facts, especially some data or stories from the people who live in US

Comment: @ChrisHayes - they are not asking. They are asserting. There's a pretty big difference between the two. If you pay attention, the word "appear" [was edited into the question to make it less objectionable *less than 1 hour ago*](http://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/16205/revisions).

Comment: I've voted to close this question as off topic because it is not about matters of policy, political processes, or conflicting egos of politicians/ideologies. While it is a good question asking about a US crime Statistic, that doesn't fit within the topics of this SE. If it were "What actions are state governments taking to mitigate a perceived rise in hate crimes against Muslims?" or related, it would be appropriate for this SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some truth to the assertion that there's more hate crimes against Muslims. However, the headlines don't tell the whole story. Take this article on CNN, entitled [FBI: Hate crimes spike, most sharply against Muslims](http://www.cnn.com/2016/11/14/us/fbi-hate-crime-report-muslims/). It makes it sound like there's a massive number of hate crimes being perpetuated, but reading the article you realize that's not the case (emphasis mine)

> In one year, anti-Muslim hate crimes in the United States **rose 67%, from 154 incidents in 2014 to 257 in 2015**, according to the latest numbers released in the bureau's Hate Crime Statistics report on Monday.
> In sheer numbers, anti-Jewish incidents (664) were higher in 2015, but **the percentage increase was much higher for incidents involving Muslim victims**.

Just in case it's not clear, while the percent went up 67%, the actual numbers went from 154 to 257 over one year. That's for the *entire country* of 330 million people. There were also 62% more hate crimes against Jews vs Muslims in the same period. But this puts the 257 crimes into perspective. The [FBI 2015 crime statistics](https://www.fbi.gov/news/pressrel/press-releases/fbi-releases-2015-crime-statistics) say

> In 2015, there were an estimated 1,197,704 violent crimes.

That's about 0.0002% of all crimes were hate crimes directed at Muslims.

Another problem is that there have been some people [reporting fake hate crimes against Muslims](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2016/11/10/women-in-hijabs-on-2-campuses-say-they-were-attacked-by-men-invoking-donald-trump) to sway political opinion against President Trump

> A student at the University of Louisiana at Lafayette fabricated a story that she was attacked and had her hijab rippped off, police said Thursday.
>
> The attack was one of several reported in the wake of Donald Trump’s election victory.
>
> In a press release Thursday afternoon, the Lafayette Police Department said that during the course of their investigation into the woman’s complaint, she “admitted that she fabricated the story about her physical attack as well as the removal of her hijab and wallet by two white males.
>
> “This incident is no longer under investigation” by the department, the statement said.

So to sum this up

1. Muslim hate crimes, as a percentage of *overall crime* is very low. It's gone up some, but the press sensationalizes the percentage, rather than the number.
2. Hate crimes are still investigated and prosecuted in the United States and that will not change, regardless of who is the President.

If your sister suffers an attack it's far more than likely it's just regular crime as opposed to targeting her for being a Muslim.

Comment: You may want to consider adding another hoax example of a Muslim student in NYC, who [fabricated (and admitted to it) a "hate crime"](http://nypost.com/2016/12/14/teen-made-up-story-about-anti-muslim-attack-on-subway/) **because she was upset at her parents over dating a Christian** (wasn't even about Trump, other than she was copycatting on the theme)

Comment: "That's about 0.0002% of all crimes". No, it's about 0.02% of all violent crimes, plus in itself a crime against basic maths. Of course with a few percent of the US population being muslims, the percentage of crimes against people who by coincidence turned out to be muslims is probably 100 times higher.